# Edge outline in sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

How to disable dark edge outlines in sculpt mode ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the viewport shading options:

Turn 'cavity' on or off.

Or change the 'valley' line size.

[image]